# Insert this symbol ^ to run below command

Tags: command-line, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I would like to run this command, but I don't know how to insert the symbol.

As this command is use to determine if the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file has the correct ownership. This command I refer to CIS in order to do host assessment.

Thank you.

```
 stat -c "%u %g" /boot/grub/grub.cfg | egrep "^0 0"
```

Comment: the ^ on my keyboard = shifted numeral 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbol `^` is called caret, it's on the same key as numeric 6 on the keyboard.

You need <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> to type `^`.

On Regex notation (as you are using `egrep`), `^` is a token that matches start of a line.

You command:

```
stat -c "%u %g" /boot/grub/grub.cfg | egrep "^0 0"
```

is necessarily checking if the file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` is owned by `root:root`.

`%u` and `%g` formats with `-c` option of `stat` prints the owner user and group of a file, `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` in this case.